# Tense of "lie"/"lay" in a clause

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, tenses, lie-lay-lain-laid

I've been using "lay" but many people have looked at my sentence dubiously.

> However, while in secondary school, I abandoned my higher scientific aspirations because I became more focused on a career rather than finding where my personal interests truly **lay**.

I think I'm trying to use "lie" in past tense, so I used "lay", but is the "finding..." clause  present-tense, so does that clash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no tense clash.  *Finding* is a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) here (a verb turned into a noun by adding *-ing*), and nouns fit with any tense.

You are also correct in supposing that the past tense of *[lie](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lie)* is *lay*, though (as FumbleFingers notes below) *lie* could actually be what you want to use; the present tense would signify that your prevailing personal interests have not changed since then.

Also, I might say *finding a job/employment* instead of *a career*, since finding or pursuing a *career* implies that you are searching out what you want to do; from the context it looks like you mean you found it necessary to take up a job just to make money, not to pursue as a career goal:

> However, while in secondary school, I abandoned my higher scientific aspirations because I became more focused on finding a job rather than finding where my personal interests truly lay.

Comment: It's true there's no tense clash, but it's not obvious to me OP couldn't have written **lie** instead - again with no tense clash. His true interests are presumably enduring, as @David says (though unlike him, I'm not convinced it makes any difference at all which tense is used for them).

Comment: Agreed with @FumbleFingers, the OP’s example is correct (grammatically and idiomatically) with either *lie* or *lay*.  The subtle difference in meaning between options like these has come up before, at **[“Yes, I thought it was very good.” Why *thought*?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8593/yes-i-thought-it-was-very-good-why-thought/)**

Comment: "However, while in secondary school, I abandoned my higher scientific aspirations as I became more focused on employment rather than finding and sating my true personal interests." and skip lie/lay altogether? :P

Comment: That would be fine ;) - only *sating* sounds a little self-indulgent.  I would use *pursuing*.

Answer (score -3):

You need the present tense here because you are making a general statement, not describing something that occurred in the past. A general statement is true all the time, so it is true NOW, thus requiring the present tense.

Also, this sentence has a parallelism problem. You are trying to match "a career" with "finding where my personal interests truly lay [lie]." I recommend this:
"...more focused **on pursuing** a career rather than **on finding** where my personal...."

Finally, remove "truly." It is unnecessary and adds no meaning in this sentence.

Comment: It looks to me like the OP *is* speaking of the past.  Also, I think *truly* does add an element of meaning to the sentence.  It is there to emphasize that the career he was pursuing was not what he was really interested in.